# Laravel Controller/Modal order by in all()

Tags: sql, laravel, sorting, controller, sql-order-by

Trying to sort my table. The numbers are `category_id` and they are not sorted by number (1 and 2 are at the bottom of the table), I want to order them.

[image: 1]

**Controller:**

```
public function fetchcategory(){
    $all_categories = HmsBbrCategory::all();
    return response()->json([
        'all_categories'=>$all_categories,
    ]);
}
```

When I try the code below, I get 500 internal server error in my console:

```
$all_categories = HmsBbrCategory::orderBy('category_id', 'ASC')->all();
```

What am I doing wrong witht the orderBy code?

Comment: Try `HmsBbrCategory::orderBy('category_id', 'ASC')->get()`

Comment: ah, so get() and all() functions the same. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for reference to know difference between `all()` and `get()`

**all()**

Its a `static method` so you cant execute additional queries.Only option you have in all() method is you can `select columns`.

```
public static function all($columns = ['*'])
{
    return static::query()->get(
        is_array($columns) ? $columns : func_get_args()
    );
}
```

If we see implementation of that static all() method. Internally it calls `get() method`

1.`all()` accept `columns as array`. Default set to `*` ,it means all columns selected.

2.Inside of that method ,we can see `get()` called. So after get we cant call any query operations so its throwing error

`get()` is Eloquent builder  `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`

Answer (score 0):

Simply you have to update this line

```
$all_categories = HmsBbrCategory::orderBy('category_id', 'ASC')->all();
```

into

```
$all_categories = HmsBbrCategory::orderBy('category_id', 'ASC')->get();
```

then you will get your result .